# What is the meaning of SetFill followed to hex? #UTF-8 conversion

Tags: c++, utf-8

```
cout << hex << setfill('0');
cout << 12 << setw(2);
output : 0a??????
```

I have no lead on UTF-8, From my understanding unless it is a non ascii character there is no difference.

What is the C++ equivalent to find the hex of a UTF-8 encoded not included in ASCII?

Correct me if i am wrong, very new to C++ if i use this expression does it mean if i take an output, let's say 12, i set 2, i will get an output of 0a?

The expression itself does not create any output of any sort.
How do i tweak it so it can take a UTF-8 character? Right now i can only deal with ASCII.

Comment: `0a` is hex for 10, not 12.

Comment: `hex` only affects printing numbers, not characters.